# search ActiveRecord through rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have 2 models:
User and Book

and a join model ownership which connect User and Book

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :users, :through => :ownerships,:uniq=>true
  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :books, :through => :ownerships
end

class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end
```

The scenario is that when user A is searching for books on my website,I return the related books which are owned by users around user A(for example,they are both in the same university).

Can I do that with rails accociation?

Comment: Try to define `scope` on `Book` that gets books by some `lambda` that receives user instance or current user. In lambda you could format your request in ordinary form, like joins(:user).where(:users => { :university_id => user.university_id} ). (Using [meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where) or [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) for Rails 3.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @Mark Guk

what i finally do is :

```
  scope :same_university,lambda{|q,current_user|
    where("title like '%#{q}%'").joins(:sell_infos).where(
      "sell_infos.university is '#{current_user.university}'")
  }
```